# jsonpath find all keys leave contains a string

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I'm using the JSON path to my elaborate.
I need to find all final leaves nodes which contain a specific string.
Suppose you have a json :

```
{  'nested' :{
              'leaf1' : 'MY_STRING_TO_FIND'
           },
   'leaf2' : 'MY_STRING_TO_FIND'
}
```

my purpose is to output leaf1 and leaf2

Comment: Are you trying to output `leaf1` and `leaf2` if their value is `MY_STRING_TO_FIND`?

Comment: yes I need that

Answer (score 0):

The json string in your question is invalid, but if I understand your question correctly and assuming the actual json string looks something like this:

```
{
    "nested": {
        "leaf1": "MY_STRING_TO_FIND",
         "leaf2": "some other string",
        "leaf3": "MY_STRING_TO_FIND"
    }
}
```

and assuming you can use [jsonpath-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus), then the following expression:

```
*[?(@ === "MY_STRING_TO_FIND")]~
```

outputs:

```
[
    "leaf1",
    "leaf3"
]
```